# How to get the number of occurrences of some words or strings from a file in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to find out the number of occurrences of some words/strings from a text file.
For example:

```
word=("ed","en","an")
text_file = open('abcd.txt', 'r').read()
```

I tried the below one:

```
import re
word = ("ed", "en", "an")
for i in word:
    targettext = open('abcd.txt', 'r').read()
    print(len(re.findall(word, targettext)))
```

I got below error:

in _compile
    raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; I'd recommend taking the tour and learning [ask].

Comment: 1) Why is this tagged `regex`? 2) What's the desired output? 3 separate numbers? 1 summed up number? Something else? 3) Have you made an attempt to solve the problem? Can we see that attempt?

Comment: I totally agree : show us your work first ! Then we can discuss what can be done

Comment: import re
word = ("ed", "en", "an")
for i in word:
    targettext = open('abcd.txt', 'r').read()
    print(len(re.findall(word, targettext)))

i got error "raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with `re` module:

```
import re

words = ('ed', 'en', 'an')

with open('abcd.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

for word in words:
    matches = re.findall(fr'\b{word}\b', data)
    print(len(matches))
```